# How to change the paragraph text to textbox text in HTML?

Tags: html

I have two inputs, and I want to when the user click in the button, the paragraph changes text to `first input`™★`second input`©. I searched this on Google and didn't found nothing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be what you are looking for.

```js
function output() {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = document.getElementById("first").value + "™★" + document.getElementById("second").value + "©";
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="first" />
<input type="text" id="second" />
<input type="submit" onclick="output()" />

<p id="output"></p>
```